# How to install/setup dependency of gem 'xmlsec-ruby', '0.0.7b'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to install the gem `'xmlsec-ruby', '0.0.7b', :require => nil` but I am getting error when i installing it `'xmlsec1 is not install'`

So please suggest me how to install its dependency on ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the following steps:

If you have Ubuntu OS then run

`sudo apt-get install xmlsec1  libxmlsec1-dev`

`brew install xmlsec1" and then "brew link libxml2"` on osx

you may need to `brew install libxslt` and then `brew link libxslt` on osx (particularly for fresh installs with later os's (mountainlion))